# Piano con Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

Hice un piano con tkinter y quiero que por ejemplo al presionar la "a" del teclado, un botón de la GUI se presione, generando así el evento. ¿Cómo?

Comment: Y el codigo? En este caso es necesario tener un [ejemplo-minimo-verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), y sobre todo, poner lo que has [intentado](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/4884/cuanto-esfuerzo-se-espera-de-los-usuarios-de-stack-overflow)

Comment: No he intentado nada porque no he encontrado información, pero aquí va el código, es grande!!

Comment: https://pastebin.com/QuK1m2Yf Ese es, quiero que se presione un botón cuando yo presione una tecla.

Comment: Te sirve si el boton no se presiona, pero se ejecuta el evento?

Comment: Utiliza el método “bind” en la root, si agregas el código podría ayudar a implementarlo

Comment: Tal como se dice, dejar el código en pastebin o similares termina en que lo borran y la pregunta se hace inutilizable para la gente en el futuro.

Comment: Perdón, es que puse que el código se autodestruyera cuando lo vieran por primera vez. Ya lo subo permanentemente...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Si lo que quieres es que el botón se presione en cuanto tocas una tecla, puedes hacerlo del siguiente modo:

```
from tkinter import *
import time

v = Tk()

def func():
    print("prueba")

b=Button(command=func)
b.pack()

def a(Event):
    #genero el evento que presiona el boton
    b.event_generate("<Button-1>")


    #actualizo la apariencia del boton para que se vea presionado
    b.update()


    #le pongo un retraso de 0.1 segundos para que espere un poco antes de dejar de presionarse
    time.sleep(0.1)


    #ejecuto la funcion
    func()


    #genero el evento que deja de presionar el boton
    b.event_generate("<ButtonRelease-1>")

v.bind("a", a)
```

---

Sin embargo, si lo que quieres es solamente que suceda el evento, es mejor hacerlo de este modo:

```
from tkinter import *
import time

v = Tk()

def func(Event=None):
    print("prueba")

b=Button(command=func)
b.pack()

v.bind("a", func)
```

Comment: Muchas gracias! Yo ponía el bind a los botones y por eso no me funcionaba.